# After dismissing the red "messages" or green "rep" notification, they are still visible on pages opened before

Tags: bug, notifications, global-inbox

I open a few pages from "hot network questions", then dismiss the inbox messages, then switch to some page.

Expected: the "1" counter disappears;

Actual: "1" counter stays until I click on it again or refresh the page.

Update: it seems to happen not all the time. I have just observed correctly disappearing red badge when I switch browser to a tab with the page.

Update 2: I have just switched to [this very](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245403/after-dismissing-the-red-messages-or-green-rep-notification-they-are-still) page and saw red "1" notification emerging. It was one I remember dismissing already...

Comment: [Always Blame Caching.](http://shouldiblamecaching.com)

Comment: Unless I manually override caching settings, caching issues should also be a concern for web developers.

Comment: Hit refresh that's it!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Bala, The feature is designed explicitly to avoid this annoying additional click. Appearance of new inbox item makes me feel there is something shiny new, and clicking on it only reveals that there is nothing new, making the mood worse than if there were no spurious notification in the first place. Spurious notification immediately disappearing in 0.5 seconds by JavaScript is lesser concern (although still a little bit annoying), as I don't start wondering what is it about.

Comment: Do you mean the notifications stay when: 1. dismiss 2. change to another tab 3. change back to first tab *OR* 1. dismiss 2. go to a different page 3. click back to return to original page? If it's the first process, can you add browser info please? If it's the second one (I experience this when using the second process), it's cached pages.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName, No, it's just "1. dismiss, 2 change to another tab". It should disappear on that tab automatically, but sometimes stays (or even appears).

Comment: "2 change to another tab. It should disappear on that tab automatically" is "that tab" the original or new ("another") tab? Is the tab you change to already on an SE site?

Comment: @EsotericScreenName, Fuller scenario: 1. Open some SE page; 2. See the inbox notification, but not click on it; 3. Open another SE page in a new background tab; 4. In current tab, dismiss the notification; 5. Switch to previously opened background tab; Expected: notification disappears always (unless there is new, second notificaion); Actual: it disappears not 100% of times (as if the previous dismission event was not propagated to server).